# 2 functions that should be the same give different results

Tags: c++, file, io, binary

I'm reading a file into a vector, to read bytes off of it. The standalone function works fine, but I don't want to open and close a file and create a vector every time i access, since im going to be grabbing lots of bytes. So I opted to put it in a file class. However, this has lead to me getting entirely different results when I use the file class.

This is a working standalone function:

```cpp
template<class T>
T readFromNewFile(std::string path, size_t size = 0, uint offset = 0)
{
    std::ifstream in(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        std::streamoff max = in.tellg();
        size_t _size = size == 0 ? (size_t)max : size;
        in.seekg(offset, std::ios::beg); 
        std::vector<uint> v(_size);
        in.read((char*)v.data(), _size);

        uint temp = 0;
        std::stringstream ss; 
        for (uint it = 0; it < v.size(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << "readFromNewFile: Adding offset: " << offset + it << ", with value: " << v[it] << "\n";
            temp += v[it];
        }
        ss << temp;
        T myVar;
        ss >> myVar;
        return myVar;
    }
    return T();
}
```

The file class in question:

```cpp
class File
{
public:
    File() {}
    File(std::string path)
    {
        LOAD(path);
    }
    ~File() {}
    void LOAD(std::string path)
    {
        std::ifstream in(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        if (in.is_open())
        {
            std::streamoff max = in.tellg();
            size_t _size = (size_t)max;
            in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            data.clear();

            data.resize(_size);
            in.read((char*)data.data(), _size);
        }
    }
    template<class T>
    T readFromVector(size_t size = 0, uint offset = 0)
    {
        uint temp = 0;
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (uint it = offset; it < (offset + size) && it < data.size(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << "readFromVector: reading offset: " << it << ", with value: " << data[it] << "\n";
            temp += data[it];
        }
        ss << temp;
        T myVar;
        ss >> myVar;
        return myVar;
    }
private:
    std::vector<uint> data;
};
```

The code is all called in this block:

```cpp
bool ArmourManager::init()
{
    std::string armourFile = "resources\\armor.am_dat";
    Offsets::ArmourOffsets offsets;    
    data.LOAD(armourFile); // data is a File object in ArmourManager class
    uint armourOffset = 0x0A;
    uint textOffset = 0x41C06;
    // armours start at offset 0x0A, increase by 0x3C for every armour in file
    // appears to end at 187390 ? 0x2DBFE‬
    //std::cout << "[OFFSET]\t[IDX]\t[RAR]\t[SLOT]\t[DEF]\t[SLOTS]\n";
    while (armourOffset < 0x2DBFE)
    {
        uint ind = SetMaker::readFromNewFile<uint>(armourFile, 4, armourOffset + offsets.Index);
        uint x = data.readFromVector<uint>(4, armourOffset + offsets.Index);
        std::cout << ind << " / " << x << "\n";
```

[Console Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzkp2.png)

From what i can tell with debugging, the data vector isn't being populated correctly, it's being filled with weird data.

[Checking first index of both vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H9vZ.png)
Even when I tried something like this,

```cpp
std::vector<uint> x(_size);
in.read((char*)x.data(), _size);
std::cout << "x byte 0: " << x[0] << "\n";
```

the result is still the exact same.

Comment: `std::vector<uint> v(_size);` is a `uint` on your platform 1 byte?

Comment: my uint is just standard. but it behaves exactly as expected with my readFromFile function.

Comment: using uint8_t as my data vector, now it loops after hitting 256

Comment: nevermind i was handling it wrong with that data type. https://i.imgur.com/PWNmb3P.png

Comment: now, how should i handle my bytes to get the right output because it’s giving like 120 1 0 0 and if i handle it like 120+(1*256) then it works for some data types but there’s one that is 00 4D 00 00 and if i add it normally it’s wayyy off when it should be 0